# Error installing jade on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, pug, npm

I get an error when pushing my node.js-app to Heroku. It used to work, but now, for some reason, it's failing.

When I push to Heroku I get the following:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
   Using Node.js version: 0.6.13
   Using npm version: 1.1.4
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.9
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/0.15.4
   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/0.15.4
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.15.4.tgz
   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.9
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-2.5.9.tgz
   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.15.4.tgz
   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-2.5.9.tgz
   npm ERR! error installing jade@0.15.4

   npm ERR! Refusing to delete: /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/node_modules/.bin/jade not in /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/node_modules/jade
   npm ERR! File exists: /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/node_modules/.bin/jade
   npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-348-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-HkEc/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-X5Wz/cli.js" "install" "--production"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4
   npm ERR! node -v v0.6.13
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
   npm ERR! path /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/node_modules/.bin/jade
   npm ERR! code EEXIST
   npm ERR! message Refusing to delete: /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/node_modules/.bin/jade not in /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/node_modules/jade
   npm ERR! errno {}
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_dzqaws2o7lx4/npm-debug.log
   npm not ok
 !     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

My package.json is ats follows:

```
{
  "name": "myAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.5.9",
      "mongoose":"3.5.2",
      "jade": "0.15.4",
      "ejs": "0.7.1"
      },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.13",
    "npm": "1.1.4"
  }
}
```

Because it says "Refusing to delete:..." I thought it might have been a freak error on Heroku, so I tried to push it to a new Heroku-app, but I get the same error.

Any ideas as to what is wrong? Is it my versions? Everything runs fine locally (windows).
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an old `node.js`. Try adding the following to `package.json`:

```
  "engines": {
        "node": "0.8.x",
        "npm": "1.1.x"
  },
```

You can inspect thing more closely by logging in on the system. First you need to install [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) (if you haven't already). Then:

```
heroku login
```

and

```
heroku run bash --app yourapp
```

This will give you a bash to your heroku installation. Navigate to `/tmp` (`cd /tmp`) and see what's left there. Try to remove it manually (`rm -rf whatisleft`).

Your jade version is out of date too (still). My heroku install with jade has:

```
"jade": "*"
```

Lastly, don't add `node_modules` to source control. So add it to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks, that definately seemed to help. I still get an error though. I've changed versions of node and npm as suggested, and changed jade to 0.27.x, and now get the following error:
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_1wpdx45enjekq/node_modules/jade/bin/jade'
Do you still think it a verson-problem, or could it be something to do with Heroku?

Comment: You have the heroku toolbelt installed? Try first 'heroku login' and then 'heroku run bash --app yourapp'. This will give you a remote shell where you check things more closely. Maybe you have to clear the /tmp folder manually.

Comment: You also have an old jade version. I'm using 0.27.7, but you can use '*', so it will be the latest version.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the version of Jade to '*', to get the latest version. Same error! I think you are right in that I need to delete the tmp-folder manually. But how? I've installed the Heroku toolbelt, and run the bash-command as suggested above, but if I run a dir- or ls-command, I get nothing in return. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I just get nothing.. Its wierd. If I write "ls", it just returns "ls", and the same with "dir". It doesn't show me any files or directories at all. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I run this command: "heroku run bash --app findthatlensadmin" and it returns "Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.6440" with a prompt of "~ $".

Comment: Normally it starts in your home/project dir, but this will be empty since the install failed. Try 'cd /tmp' and 'ls' then.

Comment: Ok, when I try that, I get the prompt "/tmp $", so I guess the tmp folder is there. However, ls and dir still returns nothing.

Comment: One last guess: did you add node_modules to git? You shouldnt since heroku will generate it based on package.json.

Comment: OMG you're a genious. That was exactly it. I removed the folder from git, and now it installs just fine. The app craches on Heroku, but that's probably because I've messed around with the versions of the installed modules. I'll have a look at that myself. Thanks for the help. I would never have figured that out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can force Heroku to clear the cache for your app:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```